# Showing content based on screen resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, screen-resolution

I have a website with some content. Based on the users screen resolution i want to show different content so that mobile devices will have some other content, but the rest of the site will be the same. I did some research, and it seems like the only possible way is with javascript. I code PHP most of the time, so i really suck at javascript, so it would be nice if someone could provide me with a simple script.

What i need is a javascript function like this:

```
if (screen resolution < X x X) {
show some content...
} else {
show some other content ...
}
```

If javascript is off, it should just show some other content.. :) I can install jquery if it helps. Thanks

It would be nice with examples for the html code too.

Comment: An identical question was asked about 5 hours ago. I'm sure someone else can find it since I failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should NOT detect if the user is on a mobile device with javascript. i recommend you this in PHP. you can use [$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)]  and then simply parse out the string to see what kind of user agent it is. I am actually implementing this same concept right now.

you can also use this class [Mobile Detect](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/)

```
include("Mobile_Detect.php");
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();

if ($detect->isMobile()) {
     // any mobile platform
}
```

Comment: Sound like a great idea, my concerns is that i need to make a damn long list with mobile user_agents , or is there a smart way of detecting this ?

Comment: You can use preg match and look for key words like iphone, ipod, andriod. or use this class. http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

Comment: i added more comment check above. Also another reason why you dont want to use client side code like javascript is becuase what if they are using a mobile device that doesnt support JS or even a desktop that has javascript disabled. they will be seeing the wrong content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css media queries to target different screen resolutions. eg:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  /* iPad in landscape orientation css */
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px{
  /* iPhone css */
}
```

More info:

- https://mislav.net/2010/04/targeted-css/
- https://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

Comment: Thank you, that could be useful some time. Right now i need to change some html content, i dont think i can do that with CSS

Answer (score 1):

Check out CSS at-rules. They allow you to specify maximum and mimimum widths for a "namespace" of CSS rules, inside which you can have different rules for smaller screens. But be careful when using those, since IE doesn't like to support good things.

```
@media screen, projection and (max-device-width: 800px) {}
@media screen and (max-device-width: 300px) {}
```

On a project I'm working on, we actually redirect to a mobile version of the page if the user-agent contains certain keywords(check out the HTTP headers from JS), and use a different stylesheet completely.

Answer (score 0):

you should try CSS media queries instead

Answer (score 0):

In don't know from PHP but in .Net you can kinda detect that they are a mobile visitor and then you can redirect them to a mobile section of the site.

Then all you really need to do is write the small site re-using your existing web controls etc.  Again, unsure if you have that concept in PHP but I imagine you would.

Comment: I dont know either, but that could be a solution. Right now i want to keep the same site/design though, just some videos should be different from mobile device

Comment: Ah ok.  If the site is small then yeah this solution may be overkill